# Tuple unpacking in lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, tuples

How should I got about rewriting this lambda to fit Python3 standards?

```
top10_popular = [k for (k, (v1, v2)) in sorted(site_freq_150users.items(),
                                           key=lambda (k, (v1, v2)): v2, reverse=True)[:10]
```

I've read that this has to do with the removal of tuple unpacking in Python3, but now I'm sure how to rewrite this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the argument list flat (i.e. 1-dimensional) by naming all the top-level arguments directly, without unpacking them. Do the unpacking later in the return expression.

In your example, you could do this by saying `v = (v1, v2)` and then creating the lambda like so:

```
lambda k, v : v[1]
```

**UPDATE:** Above does not work. Instead, you really have to put the whole item into the argument and then extract key and value from that:

```
lambda item : item[1][1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, this is not working. If site__freq_150users is a dictionary of the format {k : (v1, v2)}, I tried the following: `for (k, (v1, v2)) in site_freq_150users.items():
    v = (v1, v2)

top10_popular = [k for (k, (v1, v2)) in sorted(site_freq_150users.items(),
                                               key=lambda k, v: v[1], reverse=True)][:10]` , but got a "missing positional argument v" error. Seems like I am doing something very stupid and missing an obvious thing.

Comment: Thank you, I think that should work. I managed to do it by combining your approach,  but eliminating the lambda altogether like so: `v2_list = sorted([((v2, v1), k) for (k, (v1, v2)) in site_freq_150users.items()], reverse=True)[:10]` and then extracting to a new list: `top10 = []
for ((v2, v1), k) in v2_list:
    top10.append(k)`. Not very elegant, though, hahah.